# How I replace a pattern only once using vim script

Tags: vim

I am new in vim scripting, How I replace a pattern only once. I am using the following code.

```
%s/^\\docume.*/\\docment\[STRING\]
```

input

```
\document{A}
\document{B}
\document{C}
\document{D}
```

Expected output

```
\document{STRING}
\document{B}
\document{C}
\document{D}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `%` that  you used is the  range of lines where the  command will be
processed, in this case it means from  the first line to the last (could
also be written as `:1,$s/regex/...`).

The address specified can be of one line only as well, like:

- `:3s/regex/.../` operate in line 3 only
- `:$s/regex/.../` operate in the last line only

A    search   can    also    be    used   as    part    of   a    range:
`:/search/s/regex/replace/`. However,  just as the  `/` which we  use to
search  a file,  it  will  start the  search  after  the current  cursor
position. If you  want to match the  first occurrence of a  file you can
create move to  line 0 (before line  1) and then do the  search. It will
find  the first  occurrence,  even in  line  1. So  the  answer to  your
question is to use a range (even though it will only match a single line
in that range).

The final answer isn't `:0,/search/` though.  The `,` does not move your
cursor, so that will match line 0 to the first search find *after cursor
position*.  If you  want  to move  the  cursor in  your  range, use  `;`
instead.

Another little trick: to reuse the search  in the range as the search in
the substitution, leave the latter empty. This gives a final answer of:

```
:0;/^\\document\zs.*/s//{STRING}
```

In other words: do a substitute in the range of line 0 to first match of
the pattern, substituting the same pattern by `{STRING}` (thus operating
in one line only, the topmost match of the file).

Please check the manual for range, to know more: `:h range`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any decent way to do that. Here's what comes to my mind:

If you don't include `%` before the substitute command, then vim only replaces the first occurrence in the current line (all occurrences in a line are replaced by adding the `/g` to the end of the command.

So, you can first search the expression, which gets you to its first occurrence, and then perform the substitution (no `%`).

I tried this with the `execute` command (which is like running a vim script), but it didn't work!

```
:execute "/foo"|"s/foo/bar/"
```

But running them in two separate `execute` commands did work.

I guess the search is not working correctly in `execute` (and, therefore, vim script). If you could find any other way in your script that gets you to the beginning of the line of the first occurrence (which I hope you do) then `s/foo/bar` would only replace the first one.

Comment: You can use a search as a range, thus `:/foo/s/foo/bar/`. That will match the first `foo` after the cursor line though. To guarantee it is the first match in the document, you can create a range from line 0 to the first match (even though it is a range, only one line will match the substitution). If you use the range of `:0,/foo/` it is still not the answer, because `,` doesn't move the cursor so the match will be the first after cursor. The final answer is to use `;`. So just do a substitute with this range `:0;/foo/s/...`. Check help for `range` for more details.

Comment: @sidyll You're right. You should write that as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I added. Added a little trick about reusing the pattern too.